# What is the 1MB RAW Primary Partition on SSD Disk 0?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, ssd

I've noticed that on my Dell laptop's (Windows 10 Pro with SSD) disk 0 there is a "Partition 5": it's listed as a 1MB Basic partition, RAW, healthy primary partition.

I know that I never partitioned a 1MB part. So where is this 1MB partition from? What is this partition if it's not a EFI partition or an OEM partition?

Comment: This might be Bitlocker, if you are using it.

Comment: Just checked: the Bitlocker is not turned on.

Comment: Are you sure that it is 1M, not 100M or 300M?

Comment: Yes, 1MB. It's not the entire SSD, it's partition 5. I can't format it to NTFS due to it's 1MB size!